# Invoke AutoComplete dropdown after inserting token in bootstrap tokenfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have a small example like on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/sw8xvpza/). Simple Bootstrap tokeninput using autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
      autocomplete: {
        source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
        delay: 100
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });
});
```

By default, after selecting a token the input will still be focused, and the autocomplete is only going to auto-popup again if I focus out and in to the input field.

I would like to be able to reopen the autocomplete options once I entered a token.

I was thinking to try using the `tokenfield:createtoken` event to lose and gain focus of the input again, but that won't give the autocomplete dropdown.

```
$('#tokenfield').on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (e) {
   console.log('FOCUS IN AND OUT');
   $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').blur();
   $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').focus();
});
```

Other idea was to try using the `search` function autocomplete-ui.

```
$('#tokenfield').on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (e) {
    console.log('TRY AUTOCOMPLETE SEARCH');
    $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').autocomplete('search', '');
});
```

No luck with that either.
Pls Help! Thanks! [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/sw8xvpza/)

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not work, because event is triggered before autocomplete window is closed.

So you need **setTimeout** to get it working:

[Sample on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxn8e2gf/1/)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').blur();
  $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').focus()
}, 0)
```

As you see in example, after token was set, autocomplete window is closed and opened again immediately.

Comment: For a workaround it works better than expected. It still feels like it must be a better solution for this. When the popup opens, the next click will be ingored by autocomplete and just second click will do the selection.

Comment: Adding a click after it will set it to work at first click on autocomplete. :)

Answer (score 1):

From aeryaguzov's answer with a bit of modification (I needed to add a click to be able to select at first click after it opened)
It works fine, but it is still a workaround.

Better solutions are welcome.

```
$('#tokenfield').on('tokenfield:createtoken', function (e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
            $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').blur();
            $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').focus();
            $('#tokenfield-tokenfield').click();
      }, 0)
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/uxn8e2gf/4/)